# Wi-Fi Video Conferencing

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-tab, video-conference

My daughter will be in Japan soon, studying abroad. And she just got a Macbook Air. Meanwhile, I have Android 2.2 and a Samsung Galaxy Tab. I don't mind paying for an app, but am not too keen on monthly service bills. I want to be able to have video conferencing with her on Wi-Fi only. I imagine SIP would be the way to go.

So what is the best app out there for Android right now for doing Wi-Fi video conferencing between a Mac and a Samsung Galaxy Tab, and which lets me do unlimited calling, not charged by the minute? I don't mind paying even up to $50 for the app on each system, just to not have to pay the monthly fees. I looked at the Tango app, but it said it only installed on iPhone and Android. I didn't see a Mac or PC version for it.

Answer (score 3):

Another option will be [ooVoo](http://www.oovoo.com/Mobile.aspx?pname=MobileOverview).

The free version allows 2-way video chat between Android and Mac (plus many other platforms)

They are expected to release a version for the Galaxy Tab in February according to this http://www.cnet.com/8301-19736_1-20025684-251.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out [Yahoo Messenger](http://www.appbrain.com/app/yahoo-messenger/com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.im).  I haven't used it but it's the only video chat app that I'm aware of that can communicate with a computer.  I believe Fring and Qik only go phone to phone.  Also, keep an eye on Skype, unfortunately at the moment their Android offering is very limited.

Comment: Despite being almost the only player in this area, Yahoo messenger is unstable, 1:3 is the up and running rate, 3 is for crashing not running, and it doesn't support the front facing camera, so it's gonna be you videoing something, or you chatting in front of a mirror.

Answer (score -1):

Am using Facebook Messenger. It's safe and quite helpful and easy for me.